# R combining the characters of the first two rows of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
dnames <- data.frame(x1= c("a","b"),x2= c("c","d"),x3= c("e", "f"))
dnames
```

I would like to combine the characters of each of the first two rows of the data frame

```
dnames1 <- c("ab","cd","ed")
dnames1
```

I tried:

```
dnames1 <- paste(dnames[1,],dnames[2,],sep="")
dnames1
```

But this did not give the correct result. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can do `sapply(dnames, paste, collapse="")`  In your case, the columns are `factor`.  So, it is converted to `integer` storage mode while extracting by row.  Instead it can be `unlist` `paste(unlist(dnames[1,]),unlist(dnames[2,]),sep="")`

Comment: I think this works, too: `dnames1 <- apply(dnames[1:2,], 2, function(i) paste0(i[1], i[2]))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For column wise `paste`, use `sapply`

```
sapply(dnames, paste, collapse="")
```

Or using the OP's method, `unlist` and `paste`

```
paste(unlist(dnames[1,]),unlist(dnames[2,]),sep="")
```

---

In `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dnames %>%
   summarise_all(str_c, collapse='')
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep your code style, you can try the following code

```
d <- t(dnames)
dnames1 <- paste0(d[,1],d[,2])
```

such that

```
> dnames1
[1] "ab" "cd" "ef"
```